# How to load methods from subdir in class and use fields from class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a class

```
import functions   
Class Foo():
  functions = functions
```

And I have a subdir 'functions' with a test.py containing the following code:

```
def test()
  print("test!")
```

Now this class imports all py files from the functions directory. I can use the class like this:

```
bar = Foo()
bar.functions.test()
#prints test!
```

This works all great. But I want the test method to have access to other fields in the Foo class. Like this:

```
import functions   
Class Foo():
  functions = functions
  def __init__(self, var):
    self.var = var

def test():
  print("Hello " + class.var)

bar = Foo("User")
bar.functions.test()
#prints Hello User
```

How do I get access to the 'var' value in the test method scope?

Comment: If you want an instance method, define the method in instance scope. The methods you're defining right now aren't even methods at all. They're ordinary functions being assigned to a class variable. The fact that you can call them using a syntax that *looks* somewhat like an instance method is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I used the wrong terminology but is it possible to have instance methods loaded from seperate files?

Comment: Ostensibly, I suppose. You can always attach a method to a class after the fact with simple assignment syntax. But it would confuse every Python dev who ever reads your code. Do you need them all to be instance methods, or do a lot of them make sense as top-level functions?

Comment: What I want to achieve is a folder containing functions, so it would be easy to add, delete or modify functions. However, I need some way to give these functions access to the class fields.